# Override Kendo UI CSS

Tags: css, angular, kendo-ui

I'm trying to give round edges to my Kendo UI number box, but I am not able to override the CSS, I was able to do it in the browser debugger and manually change the `border-radius`, my CSS code is below:

```
k-numerictextbox k-numeric-wrap {
 border-radius: 10px !important;
}

k-numerictextbox k-numeric-wrap k-select {
 border-radius: 0 10px 10px 0 !important;
}
```

any thoghts would be helpful, thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Short Answer**

You need to use `::ng-deep`:

```
::ng-deep .k-numerictextbox .k-numeric-wrap {
    border-radius: 10px !important;
}

::ng-deep .k-numerictextbox .k-numeric-wrap .k-select {
    border-radius: 0 10px 10px 0 !important;
}
```

**Explanation**

Angular uses view encapsulation to prevent styles from leaking out of a component and effecting the rest of your application. This occurs by using shadow-dom. You can see that when you inspect any element that you have a class applied to how your classes now contain things like `[_ngcontent-c0]`. The problem is that your styles also don't get applied to sub-elements i.e elements that are created by child-components of your component. By using `::ng-deep` (which is [depricated](https://angular.io/guide/component-styles)) you can apply your styles to the sub-elements.

Comment: Thanks for your response Simon, I didn't try your solution but I ended up solving the problem differently, I'd give you a point for the useful answer but unfortunately I can't, since I don't have enough reputation, but Id like to know what is the difference between my solution and yours, let me know if you know. Thanks again!

Comment: Ah, I see why both your original solution and the one I have posted didn't work. There is no `.` before `k-numerictextbox` or `k-numeric-wrap` in either of our selectors but in your working solution you have shown that it is, in fact, a class and not an element `kendo-numerictextbox.k-numerictextbox` (where `kendo-numerictextbox` is an element and `.k-numerictextbox` is a class). You could probably just add those dots to your css in your question and it would work but the css in your answer is much more specific which is generally better.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution below which worked for me:

```
.settings kendo-numerictextbox.k-numerictextbox .k-numeric-wrap .k-select {
    border-radius: 0 10px 10px 0 !important;
}

.settings kendo-numerictextbox.k-numerictextbox .k-numeric-wrap {
    border-radius: 10px !important;
}
```

***Note:** `.Settings` is my wrapper class.