# changer color of kendo switch

Tags: html, css, angular, kendo-ui

So I am using the switch from kendo UI for angular.

component.html

`<kendo-switch name="isActive" onLabel="Yes" offLabel="No" class="switch" [(ngModel)]="inspectionPlan.isActive"></kendo-switch>`

It appears with it's default blue color, but I want to change it. I opened the Browser DevTools to see the names of the classes and I found this.

```
//default
.k-switch-on .k-switch-track {
    border-color: #0d6efd;
    background-color: #0d6efd;
}
```

so I went to the scss file of the component and i tried to use these classes to override the color.

component.scss

```
.k-switch-on .k-switch-track {
    border-color: red !important;
    background-color: red !important;
}
```

but It is still the default color. Where do I need to write the css style in order for it to work?

Answer (score 0):

I found this helpful [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51867248/override-kendo-ui-css). The solution is to add ::ng-deep
in front of the class names in the scss file.

component.scss

```
::ng-deep .k-switch-on .k-switch-track {
    border-color: red !important;
    background-color: red !important;
}
```